# Unable to open some activities java files

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

Today I'm not able to open some java files in Android Studio. 
They seems to contain R classes from Android Studio but if I open them from another editor they are opened right.

Here's a screeshot:

[image: screenshot]

Help.

The app debug with no errors and works

Comment: Try to check if your sdk is up to date, install all possible updates and rebuild

Comment: This is probably a bug of AS. I also was getting similar issues with it. So try to press "sync" project again or if it will not help - "invalidate caches and restart". Hope this will help you

Comment: @GiorgosDev already done that

Comment: @DmitriyMiyai didn't helped

Comment: Are you sure the name of the classes is the same as the name of their .java file names? check this with your simple editors.

Comment: @Joe Yes, absolutely

Comment: Close AS and delete the .gradle and build directories.

Comment: @m0skit0 It didn't worked

Comment: @DavideBicego once update your gradle and then check

Comment: @Varma didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it happens to me,
one way would be to close the `project` and remove it from `android studio` (in `manage projects`), then **re import** it.